# Chrome: waiting for www.site.com, how to know which resource is delaying the page load?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, pageload

When a site gets stuck in chrome with the 'loading www.site.com' status, Is there anyway to know which of the elements on the DOM is delaying the load? for example, it can be an external js file or image that is taking long time to load. I tried using the network tab in the DeveloperTools, but it only shows the elements already loaded and the time they took. I couldn't find a way to see which element is stuck.

Comment: In the development console you have a network monitor.

Comment: I'd appreciate mark the answer as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way that I'm not sure it works in all cases, but it did for me. I used the **Timeline** tab (now shown in the **Performance** tab), it's one of the tabs in Chrome Dev Tools.

1. Open Chrome Developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in Mac) and click the **Performance** tab
2. Make sure you **drag** the grey timeline bar all the way to the right, you want to see the most recent section of events so you can find what's getting stuck:

   [image: Grey bar]
3. Check just down below the records sidebar. If you don't see this like in the capture below, try toggling the icons, there are different view modes. Now, going all the way down I found these. It doesn't look like that's going well. Obviously some kind of infinite loop in some random code:

   [image]

I couldn't find out if it was an extension itself or some other bit of code. Clicking through I only could find `// Copyright 2014 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.`.

Checking in Incognito mode clear of extensions, the website loads just fine.

I'd also advise to **check the Console tab** to see if there are were any errors that might cause the *infinite loading* thing. You'll often find clues there.